# How do I get instanceID when I use spring boot admin?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I want to integrate the springbootadmin monitoring detail page into our own management system, how can I get the instanceId of the detail page？
for example localhost:8020/instances/**5f3d1f8ee6a0**/details，I want to know how can I get 5f3d1f8ee6a0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ApplicationRegistrator` class, you can create a route on the client exposing the registered id:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/instance")
class InstanceController {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationRegistrator applicationRegistrator

    @GetMapping("/")
    String get() {
        return applicationRegistrator.getRegisteredId();
    }
}
```